# Create folders based on cell values in Excel + create hyperlink

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010, directory-listing

I have the following cell values (Column `FOLDERNAME`) for which I'd like to automatically create a folder in my current spreadsheet active directory.

How to do that, this is my first question?

Inside each folder I'd like the next value (Column `DRAWING_FILE`) to be displayed as a hyperlink.

How to do that, this is my second question?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Which Operating system are you on? Windows? Mac? What Excel version are you using?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: I'm on Win 7 Pro, using MS Excel 2010

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub MakeFolders()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer
    Set Rng = Selection
    maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
    maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count
    For c = 1 To maxCols
    r = 1
    Do While r <= maxRows
        If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            MkDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c))
            On Error Resume Next
        End If
        r = r + 1
    Loop
   Next c
End Sub
```

This VBA is to create folders, but you have to select the cells that contain the folder names before running this code
Also you cannot write `/` and `\` in Windows you can use `\` for folders but not names of folders

> **Reserved Characters and Names**
>
> Most common characters can be used in naming files. However, the following characters are reserved and cannot be used in a file name:
>
> `< > : " / \ | ? *`
>
> Also, neither a space nor a period can be used at the end of a name. Further, files cannot have the following reserved device names: CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Note that the case does not matter in Windows.

It is explained on this [link](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/filenames.htm).

Comment: I've attempted to fix your [formatting](http://superuser.com/editing-help). Could you possibly explain why the OP can't use \ or `_` characters?

Comment: The VBA works for creating folders but it seems that \ can't be use either. Any luck at creating the hyperlink within each folders?

Comment: @Burgi it is explained in this link http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/filenames.htm

Comment: @Luc \ correspond to a parent folder you should create it first or modify the VBA code to create it before the other folders